# Hive-Java(jdbc) connection problems

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, derby

I'm trying to connect with hive via jdbc but it gives me the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
```

I already have running hadoop and derby. By the console of hive (in linux) I can work but once I try it for the project in java it does not work

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:9000/almacendb", "","");
```

Comment: Where did you find these connection parameters?? The legacy "HiveServer" has been deprecated for _years_ and removed from the Hive code base since V1.0 -- read the docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2%2BClients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC >> and to begin with, you need to start `HiveServer2` service for your JDBC client to have something to connect to.

Comment: How can I do that?