# Hive-Java JDBC connection problems

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am doing a program in Java and I need to connect with a database in hive. I am using mysql as metastore. Hadoop, mysql and hive work without problem. I have created my database warehousedb and the table person inside it and also I inserted datas for the hirve console. The problem is when I intent to do the connection via JDBC with this database through my Java program. I was looked for internet and I have also put all the libraries that I have indicated.

When I execute those lines appear an exeption:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:9000/warehousedb", "", "");

java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:127)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.configureConnection(HiveConnection.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at connection.Conection.getHiveConnection(Conection.java:38)
at logic.Exc.main(Exc.java:19)
```

If I try with the hiveserver2:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:9000/warehousedb", "hive", "hive");

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createUnderlyingTransport(HiveConnection.java:432)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.createBinaryTransport(HiveConnection.java:452)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:193)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:157)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at connection.Conection.getHiveConnection(Conection.java:38)
at logic.Exc.main(Exc.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 9 more
```

How can I do the connection?

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace, not just the exception message.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` > that's quite explicit! What kind of JDBC driver did you pick -- Apache or Cloudera? If Apache, did you take the "standalone" JAR?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688347/hive-javajdbc-connection-problems by same exact user -- dude, I guess it's difficult for you to even connect to the internet, but that stuff is complicated, you will need some real-life guidance (on Java and on Hadoop both)

Comment: what is your  hive version?

Comment: My hive version is 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

At first    Make Sure which jar (hive ) do you want .. because it has diferent versions The old verison jar is

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

and the newest jar is `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`
The  hiveserver2 port is `1000`

for example

```
 Class.forName(org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:hive2://192.168.1.1:10000/default);
```